# sell applications that run only on a GPL v2 Server

Tags: gpl, web, server

I have been testing Pentaho BI server community edition, and after reading their licensing terms I found out that the community edition is under GPLv2.

As you may know the server is intended to host different types of files and applications (like reports, olap cubes,etc...)

My question is : are we allowed to sell applications that run on the GPLv2 server ? (we will maybe modify the server source code a bit but we won't charge it to our clients. thus the modified GPL server will be just an execution environment or a container for the reports and applications that we intend to sell) ?

this suggests that our clients must install the GPL v2 edition first and then buy from us the reports that work on it but not their source code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to get legal advice on this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because legal advise is out of scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Disclaimer:*** I am not a lawyer. When you make a business decision based on advise from strangers on the internet and you get sued, it's your fault.

First of all, **the GPL does not forbid commercial activity**. It explicitly allows you to charge for distribution. Article 4 reads:

> You may charge any price or no price for each copy that you convey

That means you can modify GPL software and then charge a customer any price you want for your changed version. The catch is that you must license it to the customer as GPL, so the customer must get the sourcecode and the right to give it away to others under the same conditions. However, when your modifications are very customer-specific, there is nobody else the customer could sell these modifications to, so customization of GPL software can be a viable business model.

Now about your actual question. You write reports which are meant to be executed by a  GPL product. This is very similar in spirit to [the GNU GPL FAQ "If a programming language interpreter is released under the GPL, does that mean programs written to be interpreted by it must be under GPL-compatible licenses?"](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#IfInterpreterIsGPL). The answer provided by the Free Software Foundation is this:

> When the interpreter just interprets a language, the answer is no. The interpreted program, to the interpreter, is just data; a free
>   software license like the GPL, based on copyright law, cannot limit
>   what data you use the interpreter on. You can run it on any data
>   (interpreted program), any way you like, and there are no requirements
>   about licensing that data to anyone.
>
> However, when the interpreter is extended to provide “bindings” to other facilities (often, but not necessarily, libraries), the
>   interpreted program is effectively linked to the facilities it uses
>   through these bindings. So if these facilities are released under the
>   GPL, the interpreted program that uses them must be released in a
>   GPL-compatible way. The JNI or Java Native Interface is an example of
>   such a binding mechanism; libraries that are accessed in this way are
>   linked dynamically with the Java programs that call them. These
>   libraries are also linked with the interpreter. If the interpreter is
>   linked statically with these libraries, or if it is designed to link
>   dynamically with these specific libraries, then it too needs to be
>   released in a GPL-compatible way.
>
> Another similar and very common case is to provide libraries with the interpreter which are themselves interpreted. For instance, Perl
>   comes with many Perl modules, and a Java implementation comes with
>   many Java classes. These libraries and the programs that call them are
>   always dynamically linked together.
>
> A consequence is that if you choose to use GPL'd Perl modules or Java classes in your program, you must release the program in a
>   GPL-compatible way, regardless of the license used in the Perl or Java
>   interpreter that the combined Perl or Java program will run on.

So it's a tricky case which depends on technical details which are outside of my area of expertise (I have no experience with Pentaho BI server).

My final recommendation is to ask Pentaho themself for their opinion about your business model and if they consider it within their license terms or not.

Comment: thanks a lot that clears out many things for me, i have a little precision though: actually the reports that we intend to sell are not programs, they are description files (written in xml and others are written in specific code) that are read as input by the  server GPLv2 libraries and then output in the form of web documents, so from what i understand we can claim copyright on our reports ?

Comment: You always have copyright on your work - that is automatic. What you actually mean to ask is if you can license it under a different license. I would say yes, but I am not a lawyer. You should really consult a lawyer and/or Pentaho about this.

Answer (score 0):

If your software doesn't (dynamically) link to the GPL-ed server software and runs in a separate process from the server itself, then your software is considered to be a independent work (not derived from the server) from a copyright perspective. This means that you can choose any license for your software, including a closed source one that prohibits redistribution.

If your software becomes a part of the server (for example, by being loaded as a plugin), then you must distribute your software under a license that gives the users the same rights as they get with the GPL license.  This does not forbid you from charging money for your software, but it doesn't usually make much sense, because you must provide access to your source code and your users have the right to redistribute the software.

---

If you make changes to the server code itself and you distribute the modified server, you must distribute that under the terms of the GPL. This is independent of the license options you have for your applications.